# With managed file, dynamically set fileName and #upload_location

Tags: 8, forms, files

In a form I want to bulk upload jpgs renaming them using exif date information and **dynamically setting** the #upload_location according to the value of a textfield in the same form.

I have no problem with accessing the exif date information. What I don't know how to do, is dynamically set the file name and file path (actual location on the server) programmatically.

This is my form upload element:

```
$form['images'] = array(
  '#type' => 'managed_file',
  '#multiple' => TRUE,
  '#upload_validators' => array(
    'file_validate_extensions' => array('jpg'),
  ),
  '#upload_location' => 'public://photos',
  '#required' => TRUE,
);

$form['file'] = [
  '#type' => 'fieldset',
  '#title' => $this->t('File'),
];

$form['file']['name'] = [
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => $this->t('File name'),
  '#description' => $this->t(
    'Is suffixed by the exif creation date-time plus fid cleaned for urls. If not set the original file name will be used.'
  ),
];

$form['file']['path'] = [
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => $this->t('File path'),
  '#placeholder' => 'path/to/directory',
  '#description' => $this->t(
    'Path to the files sub-directory, default is "photos". Sub-dirs will be create if necessary.'
  ),
];
```

I've tried using something like this in both validateForm() and submitForm().

```
$images = $form_state->getValue('images');
$file = File::load( $images[0] );
$file->setFileName("xxx2");
$file->setFileUri("public://photos/test/xxx2.jpg");
```

Although this changes the values of the $file object, it doesn't change the real path. The jpg files are also still in /sites/default/files/photos/ with their original name plus a unique counter.

So to repeat my question:
How can I set the upload_location and the fileName of a managedFile **dynamically and programmatically** in a submitForm() or validateForm() function using methods that are not marked deprecated in drupal 8.

Comment: Try [`file_move`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21file%21file.module/function/file_move/9.0.x)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @Clive. I just read your comment, but in the mean time I found the answer myself. This is the essentials of my code in my submitForm() method. It still seems a bit hacky to me but it works.

```
$images = $form_state->getValue('images');
$file = File::load( $images[0] );

$file->setPermanent();
$file->save();

$new_filename = "photos/test/test-02.jpg";
$stream_wrapper = \Drupal::service('file_system')->uriScheme($file->getFileUri());
$new_filename_uri = "{$stream_wrapper}://{$new_filename}";

file_move($file, $new_filename_uri); // <===== The essential line!

$file = File::load( $images[0] );
dpm($file->getFilename()); // returns test-02.jpg
dpm($file->getFileUri());  // returns public://photos/test/test-02.jpg
```

Comment: This works for me too, but I had to check if the directory exists  `$this->fileSystem->prepareDirectory($directory, FileSystemInterface::CREATE_DIRECTORY);`